# Problem with centering an image in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image (rabbit 86*148 pixel).
I have this code:
I have not used  `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"` but the image is in the center of ImageView, why?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rabbit" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now, I have this code.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rabbit" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The image is on the left side. `iv.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterInside)` has no effect.

Comment: Set these attributes to `ImageView`: `android:layout_gravity="center"`, `android:scaleType="center"`. Use `centerInside` instead of `center` in `scaleType` if you do not want to crop the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your layout

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```